# How to find the session id of running jobs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to get the session id of executing jobs

```
;with JobDetails as
(
select Job_Id = left(intr1,charindex(':',intr1)-1),
       Step = substring(intr1,charindex(':',intr1)+1,charindex(')',intr1)-charindex(':',intr1)-1),
       SessionId = spid
    from master.dbo.sysprocesses x 
    cross apply (select replace(x.program_name,'SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job ','')) cs (intr1)
    where spid > 50 and x.program_name like 'SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job %'
)
select * 
    from msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
    inner join JobDetails jd on j.job_id = jd.Job_Id
```

but it throws the following error

> Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 47 Conversion failed when converting
>   from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

I tried to cast the `job_id` to `varbinary` but it produces no result

```
;with JobDetails as
(
select Job_Id = left(intr1,charindex(':',intr1)-1),
       Step = substring(intr1,charindex(':',intr1)+1,charindex(')',intr1)-charindex(':',intr1)-1),
       SessionId = spid
    from master.dbo.sysprocesses x 
    cross apply (select replace(x.program_name,'SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job ','')) cs (intr1)
    where spid > 50 and x.program_name like 'SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job %'
)
select * 
    from msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
    inner join JobDetails jd on cast(j.job_id as varbinary) = jd.Job_Id
```

but when I copy paste a `job_id` from `cte` like this

```
select job_id, name 
    from msdb..sysjobs 
    where job_id = 0x128A47A31EAB8F4DA1AD852093D815F5
```

it **works**. Any idea how to fix this query

Comment: I cannot replicate the error on my system, but think the issue is that you are attempting to perform a join based on an actual uniqueidentifier, and a self-generated job_id from the sysprocesses table.

Comment: Yes, I did. It didn't show me anything, probably because my server had no running jobs at the time. So no error, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this script

```
USE msdb   
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON   
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  
DECLARE @record_id int, @SQLProcessUtilization int, @CPU int,@EventTime datetime--,@MaxCPUAllowed int   
select  top 1  @record_id =record_id,
      @EventTime=dateadd(ms, -1 * ((SELECT ms_ticks from sys.dm_os_sys_info) - [timestamp]), GetDate()),-- as EventTime,
      @SQLProcessUtilization=SQLProcessUtilization,
      --SystemIdle,
      --100 - SystemIdle - SQLProcessUtilization as OtherProcessUtilization,
      @CPU=SQLProcessUtilization + (100 - SystemIdle - SQLProcessUtilization) --as CPU_Usage
from (
      select
            record.value('(./Record/@id)[1]', 'int') as record_id,
            record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/SystemIdle)[1]', 'int') as SystemIdle,
            record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/ProcessUtilization)[1]', 'int') as SQLProcessUtilization,
            timestamp
      from (
            select timestamp, convert(xml, record) as record
            from sys.dm_os_ring_buffers
            where ring_buffer_type = N'RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR'
            and record like '%<SystemHealth>%') as x
      ) as y
order by record_id desc 
SELECT           
            x.session_id as [Sid],
            COALESCE(x.blocking_session_id, 0) as BSid,
            @CPU as CPU,   
            @SQLProcessUtilization as SQL,  

            x.Status,  
            x.TotalCPU as [T.CPU],
            x.Start_time,    
            CONVERT(nvarchar(30), getdate()-x.Start_time, 108) as Elap_time, --x.totalElapsedTime as ElapTime,
            x.totalReads as [T.RD], -- total reads
            x.totalWrites as [T.WR], --total writes     
            x.Writes_in_tempdb as [W.TDB],
            (
                  SELECT substring(text,x.statement_start_offset/2,
                        (case when x.statement_end_offset = -1
                        then len(convert(nvarchar(max), text)) * 2
                        else x.statement_end_offset end - x.statement_start_offset+3)/2)
                  FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(x.sql_handle)
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ) AS Sql_text,
            db_name(x.database_id) as dbName,
            (SELECT object_name(objectid) FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(x.sql_handle)) as object_name,           
            x.Wait_type,
            x.Login_name,
            x.Host_name,
            CASE LEFT(x.program_name,15)
            WHEN 'SQLAgent - TSQL' THEN 
            (     select top 1 'SQL Job = '+j.name from msdb.dbo.sysjobs (nolock) j
                  inner join msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps (nolock) s on j.job_id=s.job_id
                  where right(cast(s.job_id as nvarchar(50)),10) = RIGHT(substring(x.program_name,30,34),10) )
            WHEN 'SQL Server Prof' THEN 'SQL Server Profiler'
            ELSE x.program_name
            END as Program_name,
            x.percent_complete,
            x.percent_complete, 
            (
                  SELECT
                        p.text
                  FROM
                  (
                        SELECT
                             sql_handle,statement_start_offset,statement_end_offset
                        FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r2
                        WHERE
                             r2.session_id = x.blocking_session_id
                  ) AS r_blocking
                  CROSS APPLY
                  (
                  SELECT substring(text,r_blocking.statement_start_offset/2,
                        (case when r_blocking.statement_end_offset = -1
                        then len(convert(nvarchar(max), text)) * 2
                        else r_blocking.statement_end_offset end - r_blocking.statement_start_offset+3)/2)
                  FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r_blocking.sql_handle)
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                  ) p (text)
            )  as blocking_text,
            (SELECT object_name(objectid) FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(
            (select top 1 sql_handle FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r3 WHERE r3.session_id = x.blocking_session_id))) as blocking_obj

      FROM
      (
            SELECT
                  r.session_id,
                  s.host_name,
                  s.login_name,
                  r.start_time,
                  r.sql_handle,
                  r.database_id,
                  r.blocking_session_id,
                  r.wait_type,
                  r.status,
                  r.statement_start_offset,
                  r.statement_end_offset,
                  s.program_name,
                  r.percent_complete,               
                  SUM(cast(r.total_elapsed_time as bigint)) /1000 as totalElapsedTime, --CAST AS BIGINT to fix invalid data convertion when high activity
                  SUM(cast(r.reads as bigint)) AS totalReads,
                  SUM(cast(r.writes as bigint)) AS totalWrites,
                  SUM(cast(r.cpu_time as bigint)) AS totalCPU,
                  SUM(tsu.user_objects_alloc_page_count + tsu.internal_objects_alloc_page_count) AS writes_in_tempdb
            FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
            JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s ON s.session_id = r.session_id
            JOIN sys.dm_db_task_space_usage tsu ON s.session_id = tsu.session_id and r.request_id = tsu.request_id
            WHERE r.status IN ('running', 'runnable', 'suspended')
            GROUP BY
                  r.session_id,
                  s.host_name,
                  s.login_name,
                  r.start_time,
                  r.sql_handle,
                  r.database_id,
                  r.blocking_session_id,
                  r.wait_type,
                  r.status,
                  r.statement_start_offset,
                  r.statement_end_offset,
                  s.program_name,
                  r.percent_complete
      ) x
      where x.session_id <> @@spid
      order by x.totalCPU desc
GO
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This is more than useful